# Remove white haze from the outside of a image blurred using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Ok so I have an image which is blurred, and unblurred when the dom is loaded.

```
<div class="image-wrapper-container2"><div class="image-wrapper orig" style="background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-position: bottom; background-color: #a5a0a5; filter: blur(15px);"></div></div>
```

But the trouble with this is there is a white haze around the outside of the image.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nyLr8c6o/17/) to demonstrate whats going on

As you can see, I tried to remove the haze by using `width: 110%;margin-left: -5%;height: 110%;margin-top: -5%;` for the second image. but this is not the right solution.

Once the dom is loaded and the image is unblurred the image is outside the div by 5%;

Is there any way I can get the image haze to disappear from around the edge of the image without the image going outside the boundary of the `image-wrapper-container2` div element

Cheers

Comment: You could mix different svg filters to avoid it. See e.g [this good explanation by Taylor Hunt](https://codepen.io/tigt/post/fixing-the-white-glow-in-the-css-blur-filter). Here it is applied to your case : https://jsfiddle.net/4k10yozs/

Comment: @Kaiido Hi thanks for the help :) is there a way to transition this method. https://jsfiddle.net/gg5g5fgh/5/

Comment: No, not from CSS at least...

Comment: Oh damn yeah I need a transition effect :/ any pointers on how to accomplish it. Cheers :)

Comment: Well... If you don't need IE support, then you could use SMIL : https://jsfiddle.net/gg5g5fgh/9 but that begins to be completely hackish... and even chrome seems to have a buggy behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here is the solution,

As @Kaiido suggested I needed to use the svg filters method.

But for internet explorer I needed to generate a base64 image, with a small resolution. 10px x 10px
Then load the base64 image for internet explorer, which created a blurred effect when the image is streched to fit the container.

For the transition to a non blurred image, I used the SMIL transition for browsers which support it. filter: blur transition for browsers which don't support SMIL and no transition for IE the image is just swapped.

HTML:

```
    <svg width="0px" height="0px"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

 <filter id="better-blur" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="25" result="blurred">
  <animate id="anim" attributeType="XML" attributeName="stdDeviation" from="25" to="0" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze"
        dur="0.35s"></animate>
  </feGaussianBlur>

  <feMorphology in="blurred" operator="dilate" radius="25" result="expanded"></feMorphology>

  <feMerge>
    <feMergeNode in="expanded"></feMergeNode>
    <feMergeNode in="blurred"></feMergeNode>
  </feMerge>
</filter>
</svg>
<div class="image-wrapper orig" style="background-image: url(\'' . esc_url($thePostThumbUrl) . '\'); background-size: cover; background-position: bottom; filter: url(#better-blur);visibility: hidden;"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (!jQuery("#anim")[0].beginElement) {
        jQuery(".image-wrapper").css("filter", "blur(25px)");
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (jQuery("#anim")[0].beginElement) {
                jQuery("#anim")[0].beginElement();
            }
            else {
                jQuery(".image-wrapper").css("filter", "blur(0px)");
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.image-wrapper {
transition: 0.25s filter linear;
-webkit-transition: 0.25s filter linear;
-moz-transition: 0.25s filter linear;
-o-transition: 0.25s filter linear;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
overflow: hidden;
display: block;
}
```

Thanks Kaiido for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way to remove the blurry edge around elements within the `filter:blur` rule. I would suggest a simple trick instead:

1. Create two overlapped divs containing the same image, the first one containing an `img` element with the image, and the second one as an empty div with the same image as a background.
2. Inside the superior div, insert the image centred inside a bigger wrapper, creating the effect of a border around it, thick enough to contain the blurry edge. Then apply the `filter:blur` to the whole wrapper, making the blurry edge fit the fake border; then, adjust the dimensions of the image you wish to show, through `overflow:hidden`.
3. Via JavaScript, just hide the superior div on load.

```js
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.fake-image').hide();
    }, 2000);
```

```css
.fake-image {
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 560px;
      height: 360px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      left: 50px;
      z-index: 10;
    }

    .container-backup{
        width: 680px;
        height: 480px;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
        filter: blur(15px);
        margin-left: -60px;
        margin-top: -60px;
    }

    .image-top img{
      padding:  40px;
      display: block;
    }

    .real-bck-image {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      left: 50px;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 560px;
      height: 360px;
      background-image:  url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      margin: 0 auto; 
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fake-image">
  <div class="container-backup">
    <div class="image-top">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="real-bck-image"></div>
```

I hope it helps!

Cheers